# Frivolous/"super-downvote" flagging of Meta Stack Exchange answers as VLQ/NAA

Tags: discussion, flags, meta, low-quality-posts, abuse

Recently, on this same site, I reviewed https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/42346. That was a two-day-old discussion answer on a discussion question and required two <kbd>Looks OK</kbd> to dismiss, so it wasn't an auto-flag. And given the content, I can't see any way anyone who knows what Meta is for could sincerely flag that as either VLQ or NAA. (It's *further suggestions for/amendments to* a pending feature. How much more answer-y can you get?)

It's bad enough that we have to live with downvotes for disagreement as an unfortunate but natural consequence of using Meta for opinion-based questions (aka [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)). Using **flags** for disagreement are a whole nother story, and I for one find that pretty despicable. "I don't like what you're saying, so I'm going to ask some reviewers to delete it" is a really terrible way to go about policy decisions. And while we already discourage using flags for *wrong* answers on all sites, it doesn't seem that that's enough to prevent a fair number of flags for answers that are only *subjectively disagreed with*, policy-wise. (Although this does not appear to show up on any other site than M.SE.)

Can we actively discourage this in some way, perhaps simply through Meta consensus?

Similar recent reviews: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/42344), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/42272).

Comment: That question shows a consensus on the issue; idk if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheTux: Not exactly. This is a bit beyond that, and it's unique to Meta. (I've not seen it on site metas, even, although I wouldn't be too surprised if it shows up occasionally.)

Comment: It needed two "looks ok", so it was two flags.

Comment: Yeah, met some of those flags in review queues, and declined them. That's all I can do. Share your feelings. Don't know why you are being DV'ed.

Comment: @DeerHunter: Thanks. Maybe the downvoters aren't catching the distinction between normal-site flagging bad behavior and Meta-only misbehavior? Maybe they *want* super-downvotes? I don't know either, but it's certainly an unpleasant surprise to get such a chilly reception.

Comment: The duplicate doesn't apply as this post is explicitly about flagging in MSE which has its own dynamic as stated by the OP. Closing this is denying that dynamic and the needed discussion.

Comment: @rene agreed - MSE is a special case and deserves its own discussion

Answer (score 8):

Any user can *ask* for an answer to be deleted, but it takes a lot of people to say "yes" before it actually *is* deleted, and that's very unlikely to happen. Just keep reviewing these the way you have been.

Too many declined flags also leads to a flag ban. The system will take care of this if it's a systemic problem on the part of the flagging user.

Comment: We can at least discourage these flags a bit more, I think.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Sounds like an important part to include in your question, if that's what you're asking for

Comment: I assumed that's what [tag:discussion] was for....

Comment: Keep in mind on MSE, there are only about 90 users who can cast delete votes on answers (at the time of this writing). The LQ review queue changes that slightly but it still takes number of recommend delete votes to remove an answer.